# How do I include the original url as a request parameter, when proxying?

Tags: proxy, nginx

I want to proxy the incoming requests with an nginx instance to a little java backend application. The idea is that I want every original request's uri to be included as a request parameter i.e. something like:

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000?url=$request_uri;
        }
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 8):

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000$request_uri;
        }
```

The `@request_uri` is equal to the *original* request URI as received from the client including the args.

The `$request_uri` of this post is `/questions/16188521/how-do-i-include-the-original-url-as-a-request-parameter-when-proxying`.

see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24request_uri

Comment: If I do that, it tells me "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later" the next time I try to access it